# Is it possible to convert html text(string) to pdf using LEADTOOLS?

Tags: pdf, leadtools-sdk

I am trying to convert text containing html data to PDF using LEADTOOLS but i didn't get any example which is converting string to PDF directly, However i am able convert that string into text(.txt) or HTML(.htm) file first and then convert it to PDF.

Comment: freebird,
There are a handful of different ways that you could achieve this based on what you’re looking for in your output. As you may know, PDF supports two different types of documents, Raster and Vector. With Raster you’ll get the HTML rasterized into a set image embedded within the PDF, but if you do a Vector based PDF you’ll be able to highlight and search for text, or any other capabilities of vector documents. What type of PDF are you looking to generate?

Comment: will size increase if i use Vector based PDF? if no then i would like to use vector base pdf. can you please share how to convert it?

Answer (score -1):

**This answer has been re-written to improve it, to address old comments, and to make it relevant with the current version 21 of LEADTOOLS:**

The most straightforward way to do this using the LEADTOOLS toolkit would be to use the [Document Converter](https://www.leadtools.com/help/sdk/v21/dh/doxc/documentconverter.html) class with the HTML string as an input, configured to produce the desired PDF output.

The saved HTM file can be loaded and used as a source as in the example below or the original text string can be passed to the ***htmlString*** variable.

The resulting code example would be as follows, using C#:

```
using (var documentConverter = new DocumentConverter())
{
   string htmlString = File.ReadAllText(@"./test.htm");
   using (var ms = new MemoryStream(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(htmlString)))
   {
     var htmlDocument = DocumentFactory.LoadFromStream(ms, new LoadDocumentOptions());
     var jobData = DocumentConverterJobs.CreateJobData(htmlDocument, "output.pdf", DocumentFormat.Pdf);
     var job = documentConverter.Jobs.CreateJob(jobData);
      documentConverter.Jobs.RunJob(job);
   }
}
```

Comment: Why don't  provide an actual example instead of links? We have purchased this product (which is very expensive) but the documentation is so poor that we don't know where to start.

Comment: OP is asking for an example, none provided.  As I'm also interested in this and your answer is unclear, I second Felix's response, why no example?